# How to load images from webserver in xcode using Three20?

Tags: xcode, image, three20, gallery

I'm trying to make an Image Gallery App using Three20 and what I want to do is get images stored on a webserver and store them in a NSMutalbeArray and display them in thumbnail view.
I've gone through Three20 Photo Gallery tuts but everywhere its either local images or passing links of all images in code. while my problem is Images will be added frequently to the server so its not a good idea to update code and send app update everytime an image is added to the server.
it seems i'll have to use for( ) loop but i don't know how to store images in NSMutableArray and use it in for( ) loop to get all the available images.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know Three20 but what i can tell you is that you can use ASIHTTPRequest to download the images and store them locally to display them later.

See documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement the `<TTPhoto>` protocol and provide remote URLs when you define the

```
- (NSString*)URLForVersion:(TTPhotoVersion)version
```

method. Have you tried this?